# How can I attach a class to an object in Blender Game Engine 2.79b using Python 3.6.5?

Tags: python, game-engine

How can I attach a class to an object in Blender Game Engine 2.79b using Python 3.6.5?  I need the class to be attached to an object once it is initialized.

Comment: There is no such thing as an object having a reference to a class in class-based object-oriented programming languages. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) for that. I am sure your question aims at something different, like a reference to a static class for example. Please be more precise.

Comment: I am not trying reference a static class.

Comment: I am not trying to reference a static class but rather a dynamic class.